# Facebook login button showing after 1 second page loaded

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to learn Facebook login and find how can I integrate to a `asp.net` MVC project. First, I am trying to learn in normal html version in my website I used Facebook login button from docs. But when my page loaded it takes 1 or 2 seconds to show my Facebook button. How can I solve this problem. My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<body>
<script>

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '2194615170807288',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.2'
    });
     // FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
     //   statusChangeCallback(response);
   //   });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/tr_TR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2&appId=2194615170807288';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email', function(response) {
        document.getElementById("fname").value = response.first_name;
        document.getElementById("lname").value = response.last_name;    
        document.getElementById("email").value = response.email;  
     });
    } 
    else {
      document.getElementById("fname").value ="";
        document.getElementById("lname").value ="";    
        document.getElementById("email").value =""; 
    }
  }
</script>
<div>
        <form>
                First name:<br>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname"><br>
                Last name:<br>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lname"><br>
                Mail:<br>
                <input type="text" name="mail" id="email"><br>
              </form>

</div>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true" scope="public_profile,email" auth_type="rerequest" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></div>

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" auth_type="rerequest" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are loading an external script here, that takes it’s time. There isn’t much you can do about this.

Comment: please format your code

Comment: can i copy sdk to my files like bootstrap.js and load from there ? @misorude

Comment: I don’t think that is recommendable. If you don’t load it from its original domain, then likely a lot of the stuff relying on cookies and cross-domain communication won’t work properly.

Answer (score 0):

As misorude pointed out in a comment, loading the external script takes time and you cannot do anything about that. There is a solution to immediately show a login button though:

- Use your own login button (make sure to follow the guidelines: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/best-practices#brandedlogin)
- Call [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) on button click

Of course you can still use `FB.getLoginStatus` to check if the user is logged in already. Downside: Before loading the JS SDK and using `FB.getLoginStatus`, you do not know if the user is logged in already. You could show a loader for that though, so the 1-2 seconds are not really a problem for users.

Answer (score 0):

fbAsyncInit

it is async function so it wait for callback after than it will initialize.
(1 or 2 seconds is not too much time)

Comment: but i never saw a website wait facebook button load thats why i am asking where did i wrong :(

Comment: can you show us a website with a facebook button that loads immediately? i assume they are just doing what i described in my answer: using a custom login button instead.

Comment: maybe they are using same button thats why i am confused thanks